# <img> title attribute to be displayed in <html> tags below <img> using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Im kind of stuck.

When images are added to a post in my page it is displayed like this

```
<p>
  <img title="Some image title" src="img.jpg" alt="someALt" width="656" height="210" />
</p>
```

I managed to grap the `title attribue` using `Jquery` and display it below the image like I want to.

```
var title = $('img').attr('title');
 $('img').after(title);
```

My problem is that I want to be able to modify the text, like wrap it in `<small>` tags and change 'color' etc  via this jquery snippet.

I'm not sure how to do that, I have tried to add `.append()`, `.html()` and more to the  `$('img').after(title);` with out any result.

can someone guide me to the right path?

Comment: `$('img').after('<span>'+title+'</span>');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can provide a function to `after()` which runs under the scope of the current `img` element. As such you can access the `title` property from the `this` keyword. The function needs to return the HTML string to be added to the DOM, so you can just concatenate whatever elements you need in to that string.

The benefit of this is that it will work for an infinite number of `img` elements without needing any modification.

Note in the example below that I added an attribute selector to ensure that all the selected `img` elements have a `title` attribute to read.

Once that is done, the styling can then be done externally from the JS by using CSS. Try this:

```js
$('img[title]').after(function() {
  return `<small>${this.title}</small>`;
});
```

```css
img + small {
  color: #C00;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img title="Some image title" src="img.jpg" alt="Some image alt" width="656" height="210" />
</p>
<p>
  <img title="foo bar" src="img.jpg" alt="foo bar alt" width="656" height="210" />
</p>
<p>
  <img title="fizz buzz" src="img.jpg" alt="fizz buzz alt" width="656" height="210" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed :)